# How can I access the preferences of a file that is added to my activity with addPreferencesFromResource(id)?

Tags: java, android, xml, preference

I have two preference files in my `res/xml/` folder, named "preferences.xml" and "exampleprefs.xml". The object representing "preferences.xml" is accessed by

```
getSharedPreferences("com.example.project_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

or simply `getDefaultSharedPreferences()`.

How can I access "exampleprefs.xml" if it is added to my activity with `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.exampleprefs)`?

UPDATE: I figured it out. I had to call `getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("exampleprefs")` before calling `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.exampleprefs)` to set its name.

Comment: you get it with getDefaultSharedPreferences too. in exchange between preferences you use addPreferencesFromResource

Comment: Then how do I access the other preferences file within the same activity?